# VS 2013 Web Developer Tools error

Tags: visual-studio

I am using VS 2012. It is working fine. Then I installed 2013 also. VS2013 Installation was successfully completed. After completed of installation i tried to create new website But I am getting below error.

"The Web Developer Tools option must be installed prior to opening or creating Web projects. You can install this option by repairing your Microsoft Visual Studio installation and ensuring that 'Web Developer Tools' is checked in the list of optional components"

Please give me the suggestions, without disturbing the VS2012 how can I solve the above problem.

Comment: Did you try repairing with the web developer option checked?

Comment: Yes, now I am Repairing the VS2013. Let us see how it will work

Comment: I am facing same problem, after repairing the VS2013

Comment: Is it only web projects that are causing the issue? Can you try other project types? Also what type of web project is it?